# Hard Drive Squeak/Click While In Low Usage State

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have just recently upgraded my PC to a solid state, with the previous HDD still attached for storage purposes. I have noticed that the drive makes a kind of squeak/gentle click every minute or so. The drive never did this while it was the primary/active drive.

My question is, is this drive failing? It's nearing 2 years old at this point, but I have never heard this squeak while the drive was in use as the primary drive.

Another note is that while running a ChkDsk on the drive, I do not hear the squeak/click. This leads me to believe that if the drive is in a low-usage state, the squeak becomes more apparent. Is this a logical conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the previous HDD has not:
- been dropped
- out of use for a long time
- physically mounted in a different plane (horizontal vs vertical)
AND that it is possible to read and write files,
THEN the click is most likely the sound of the drive's heads 'parking' due to low usage (as you said).  The BIOS settings for the HDD may have options to change the drive's motor run-down time, i.e. the delay before parking heads.

The Squeak may be a sign to worry about the age of the HDD (fluid bearings are typically used and the fluid can dry out and cause a squeak).  But before you condemn the HDD, you may want to try it in its previous horizontal or vertical orientation, with its original power connections.

By far the safest option is replace the HDD rather than suffer a loss of data, but if you do regular backups (and of course you do) that is less of a worry.

Comment: The drive was mounted the same way as before, horizontally. It was not dropped, and it was in use up until I changed it out for the SSD. I can also read and write fine. I'll check out the BIOS to see about a run-down time. I will probably buy a drive to keep spare, since it is getting to show its age. Thanks!